# Darcy's law in non-porous media

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I learned in my hydrology class that Darcy's law describes the flow discharge in porous media: $Q=-AK\frac{dh}{dl}$ where $Q$ is flow discharge, $A$ is the area of section where fluid flows, $K$ is the hydraulic conductivity, and $dh/dl$ is the gradient of hydraulic head.

While there are some constraints on the situation when Darcy's law is valid such as laminar flow through the porous media. I became quite curious if Darcy's law would be valid if there are very few grains inside the pipe while the flow is still laminar.

We can think of the situation where Darcy's law works and continuously get rid of small amounts of grains so porosity will increase. Then, at the end, there will be no pores at all i.e. full of water. Does Darcy's law still work or is there some kind of transition point of porosity when Darcy's law becomes invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Darcy equation would still work, but then you call it the [Darcy-Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation).

In the laminar regime, this equation basically reduces to the Darcy law, where the pressure gradient is proportional to the flow rate. $K$ in that case is related to the viscosity of the fluid and the diameter of the pipe.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? It seems that the flow  in the laminar regime basically roots from the frictional loss of energy (ex. friction between fluid and pipe wall). Then, if the fluid flows through a pipe and the mechanical energy is perfectly conserved then is it deduced that there should be no flow at all?

Comment: Sustaining the pressure difference is the driving force and source of energy. It's the pump doing work.